# PHP: Understanding the include scope with spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, scope, include, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to autoload Classes, but I'm hindered by the scope. The Class is being loaded, but I'm using it out of scope. Here's the code to further explain what I'm trying to do.

**AutoLoader.php**

```
<?php
class AutoLoader {
    private $namespace;

    public function __construct($namespace) {
        $this->namespace = $namespace;

        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'ClassLoader'));
    }

    private function ClassLoader($class) {
        $class = "classes/{$this->namespace}/{$class}.php";
        print("Loading class: {$class}");
        include "{$class}";
    }
}
?>
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $loader = new AutoLoader("myspace");

    $MyClassObj = new MyClass();
    $result = $MyClassObj->MyClassFun();
?>
```

So when it comes down to `script.php`, I get the print out that it's loading the class and I don't get any errors that it can't find the file. So it looks like it's loading, but when I use the class to create a new object, it tells me it can't find the class. So I'm loading the include out of scope.

I included the `AutoLoader` in a separate file so I could load it into multiple files. Am I able to make this work or must the AutoLoader be part of `script.php` instead of separate?

*edit*: Including error, added error display to script.php.

```
Loading class: classes/myspace/MyClass.php
Fatal error: Class 'MyClass' not found in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/scripts/script.php on line 5
```

*edit*: Including MyClass.php and directory structure

**MyClass.php**

```
<?php
    class MyClass {
        public function MyClassFun() {
            $var = "hello world";
            return $var;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Directory Structure**

```
htdocs/scripts/script.php
htdocs/classes/myspace/MyClass.php
htdocs/AutoLoader.php
```

If I change the class to `MyClasse` *(misspelled)* it will error on the include because it can't find the file. So using the proper `MyClass` I can only assume that it's finding the file since it's not producing an error. So the include looks good, but it still won't use it.

Which, now that I think about it more, is strange. The include is only occuring because of line 5 when I go to use the class. `ClassLoader` is being called by the `spl_auto_register` to search for the class. It's finding and including the class. Yet the same `line 5` fails to actually use it.

I guess I don't understand that disconnect. `Line 5` is properly calling the `ClassLoader`, but then fails to actually find the class once loaded.

Comment: Can you add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` on top your script.php to dump all the errors. Your code looks correct; besides i even tried it and working as it's supposed to be.

Comment: @abeyaz: I edited the main post with the error. Strange, do I need to edit anything in the ini to make this work?

Comment: there must be sth missing coz the code is correct. Are you sure the file "classes/myspace/MyClass.php" exist and the class defined correctly in that file ?

Comment: @abeyaz: Edited main post again. The files exist. If I change the class I'm trying to load by misspelling, it fails on the include instead.

Comment: Using autoload, class only loads when its called. Thats why it fails on that line. Can you write some `file_exists` check on autoload method so we can be sure everything is okay with the path. Or you can use full path for include.

Comment: Your code works for me as you have it so you have something else going on there.